# Minimum value from range of Array

Tags: swift

I have a list of prices and want to find the minimum price EXCLUDING the first element (this is a subset of another problem on HackerRank).

My version is too slow and times out. I suspect this is due to my ArraySlice.

Here is my (working) code:

```
func calculateMins(prices: [Int]) {
    for j in 1..<prices.count  {
        let lowestPreviousPrice = prices[1...j].min()!
        print (lowestPreviousPrice)
    }
}

calculateMins(prices: [4,8,2,4,3])
```

Is there a better performing version of this, perhaps one that does not use an ArraySlice?

Comment: Why just you can't use `Array.min()` function?

Comment: Needs to be a subset of the array (I've overly reduced the problem) I'll change this example to excluding the first element instead.

Comment: What will be the output?

Comment: Let's just take it as the min of an array, EXCLUDING the first element. Have updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `dropFirst()` function.

```
var array = [1,8,2,4,3]
var array2 = array.dropFirst() // Returns a subsequence containing all but the first element of the sequence.
array2.min() // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not keep it simple

```
func calculateMins(prices: [Int]) {
    var min = Int.max
    for i in 1..<prices.count {
        if prices[i] < min { min = prices[i] }
    }
    print(min)    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have few options to solve this issue.

```
//Default way
prices.dropFirst().min()

//Functional way
prices.dropFirst().reduce(Int.max, { min($0, $1) })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `suffix`, which is quite same as `dropFirst` that this version could crash if in case array is empty.

```
array.suffix(from: 1).min()
```